# How to handle literals in templates?

Tags: c++, templates, literals

I am facing a problem, which, I am sure, lot of others must have faced already.
How to handle literals in Templates ?
Please refer my code:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
static void Swap( T& a, U& b )
{
        T temp;
        temp = a;
        a    = (T) b;
        b    = temp;
}

int main()
{
   int i = 10, j = 20;
   //! Working
   Swap<int,int>(i,j);

   int p = 50; double q = 100.0;
   //! Working
   Swap<int,double>(p,q);

  //How to handle this case ?
   Swap<int,int>(5,10);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would it even mean to swap literals?

Comment: One thing to do is use `std::swap` unless you have a good reason to do otherwise (and in this case, you apparently don't, since it looks like it'll do anything at least as well as yours).

Comment: This question doesn’t have anything to do with templates, really. I almost edited the question accordingly but stopped because but maybe I’m missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual problem is. `Swap<int, int>((int()), int())` can't be handled by your code either, but involves no literals.

Answer (score 2):

Since `5` and `10` are rvalues, they can't be passed by reference.

Besides, the call doesn't even make sense:

```
 Swap<int,int>(5,10);
```

Do you expect `5` and `10` to be swapped between each other or what?

Comment: In Soviet Russia, five is ten.

Comment: @KerrekSB actually, in Soviet Russia, 5 and 10 swap Swap.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to bind a temporary to an reference, which is not allowed by the standard.
You can only bind temporaries to a const reference. Given that You should rethink your logic.

Comment: right, but, i have no control on how the client is going to use my swap function

Comment: You can also bind temporaries to non-constant rvalue references.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, Indeed In C++11.

Comment: @Atul " i have no control on how the client is going to use my swap function " - **WRONG!** that's exactly (well, one of the reasons) why `const` and `&` exist.

Comment: @Atul there is a reason `std::swap` does not work in this case: **it makes no sense**.